# Install KSH on RHEL 6.5

Tags: rhel, software-installation, ksh

I've been handed a RHEL 6.5 server that needs KSH installing on.

That admin is not in work at the moment and we don't have a RHN subscription to download and install packages so I guess that I need to locate a RPM and install it manually, from what I've read online.

I usually only admin Debian/Ubuntu servers so I'm not sure where I would find a KSH RPM that I can install on a RHEL 6.5 server as we don't have access to `yum` command. Is there somehow I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KSH (ksh-20120801-10.el6.x86_64.rpm) comes in default with RHEL 6.5. Check if it is already there or not:

```
rpm -q ksh
```

and

```
which ksh
```

Else you can download the rpm package from the below link, mount it and install the package:

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/24622322/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/ksh-20120801-10.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: It wasn't installed so I downloaded it from your link and installed it. Thanks.

Comment: Jack, installing third-party RPMs (for scientific Linux nonetheless!) is not a good strategy. Get them from Redhat if you have RHEL.